# How to run composer update after docker-composer make container and mount volumes?

Tags: docker-compose, composer-php

I have container with php and composer inside.
How can I run composer update after  was made container?

```
php-fpm:
      build: phpdocker/php-fpm
      restart: always
      container_name: jobtest-php-fpm
      working_dir: /application
      volumes:
        - ./src:/application
        - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.2/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Comment: Typically I'd run installation commands like this in a custom Dockerfile, in a `RUN` command after I `COPY` the application source in.

Comment: Thanks, David Maze. I used your advice.  Also, I added build context to dockerfile: ```build:      dockerfile: ./phpdocker/php-fpm/Dockerfile        context: ./  . ```So, I can COPY folder and than RUN composer update

Answer (score -1):

You have to exec into the container and run the command:

```
docker-compose exec php-fpm bash

composer update
```